# triggerHandler() in angularJs not triggering click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I want to click a submit button from another button using angular `triggerHandler()`. But it doesn't seem to trigger anything even though it's getting the element it needs to get before triggering click on it.

```
<input type = "submit" name="test" value="testSubmit" ng-click="onClickSubmit();"/>
```

Controller:

```
function onClickSubmit(event) {
//$event.stopPropagation();
$timeout(function() {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#registerAccount')).triggerHandler('click');
  console.log('document.querySelector(#registerAccount)',document.querySelector('#registerAccount'),angular.element(document.querySelector('#registerAccount')));

}, 0);
};

$scope.onClickSubmit = onClickSubmit;
```

What I want is when someone clicks `Register` button on below form, if it's not valid it throws an error like displayed below. What I want is to click this button from another button called `testSubmit` below `next` button.

But currently, it's not triggering the click even though it's getting the element it needs to click. pic 2 shows the behaviour.

[image]

[image]

Above 2nd pic shows what is happening when I'm clicking `testSubmit`. It's not triggering anything. But console is displaying that it is getting the element to be clicked by `id : registerAccount`
What I'm missing here. I need this functionality .

Comment: I never tried to use "triggerHandler()", maybe you can just try to call "click()" on that element?

Comment: @BenBracha only if he has jQuery loaded. jqLite doesn't do that. triggerHandler is _supposed_ to be the proper function to use, however I'm experiencing the exact same issue as Cyclotron3x3